# Почему может не работать bash скрипт

Tags: bash

Создал простой скрипт, который должен искать названия из 1 файла в другом, если он не нашел название, то должен удалять строку из 1 файла. А после всего скопировать то, что осталось в 3 файл.

```
#!/bin/bash

name1=sitelist1;
name2=sitelist2;
strfile1=$(wc -l $name1);
strfile1=$(echo $strfile1 | tr -d $name1);
for((i=1; i < strfile1; i++)) do
str=$(head -n $i $name1 | tail -n 1);
numb_str=$(grep $str $name2);
if [[ -n $numb_str ]]; then
echo "1";

    if [[ $i -ge $strfile1 ]]; then
    sed '/^$/d' $name1;
    sed '/./!d' $name1;
    cp $name1 sitelist3.txt;
    fi
else

line=$(echo $i'd');
echo "0";

#delete string
sed $line $name1;

    if [[ $i -ge $strfile1 ]]; then
    sed '/^$/d' $name1;
    sed '/./!d' $name1;
    cp $name1 sitelist3.txt;
    fi
fi
done
```

Comment: ну накидай по коду разных echo с выводом информации, станет ясно работает или нет и если нет. то до какого места доходит

Comment: "не работает" не является описанием проблемы

Answer (score 2):

Попробуем разобраться:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

name1=sitelist1;
name2=sitelist2;
strfile1=$(wc -l $name1);
strfile1=$(echo $strfile1 | tr -d $name1);
#Лишнее переобъявление переменной, возможно выполнить
#strfile1=$(wc -l $name1 | tr -d $name1); 

for((i=1; i < strfile1; i++)) do
    str=$(head -n $i $name1 | tail -n 1);
#Не известно что в файле, если могут быть пробелы, то следует использовать экранирование кавычкой "
    numb_str=$(grep "$str" $name2);
#___________________^____^_________
    if [[ -n $numb_str ]]; then
        echo "1";
        if [[ $i -ge $strfile1 ]]; then
            sed '/^$/d' $name1;
            sed '/./!d' $name1;
#две команды выше просто выводят значения в терминал, не изменяя сам файл
#возможно пропущен ключ -i
            cp $name1 sitelist3.txt;
        fi
    else
        line=$(echo $i'd');
#echo здесь не нужно, сработает и так:
#line=${i}d
        echo "0";

        #delete string
        sed $line $name1;
#Опять же отсутствие у sed ключа -i не вносит никаких изменений в файл
        if [[ $i -ge $strfile1 ]]; then
            sed '/^$/d' $name1;
            sed '/./!d' $name1;
#аналоигчная проблема, возможно пропущен параметр -i
            cp $name1 sitelist3.txt;
        fi
    fi
done
```

По итогу скрипт никак не меняет содержимое файлов, а лишь печатает их в stdout, если изменения нужно вносить в файл, то воспользуйтесь параметром программы `sed`, `-i` который перезаписывает файл с новыми значениями

Comment: А еще лучше не вызывать sed в цикле, а накопить удаляемые строки в файле в виде директив удаления для sed-a и вызвать его с этим файлом (ключ -f) и ключем -i один раз